# Use jQuery to alter css for "html" and "*"

Tags: jquery, html, css

Apologies if this is incredibly easy but I want to be able to do the following in jQuery.

Current CSS

```
* { cursor: url('/web/resources/graphics/blank.cur'), pointer; }

html { cursor: url('/web/resources/graphics/blank.cur'), pointer; }
```

Desired CSS change (through jQuery only)

```
* { cursor: url('/web/resources/graphics/blankDot.cur'), pointer; }

html { cursor: url('/web/resources/graphics/blankDot.cur'), pointer; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("*").css("cursor", "url('/web/resources/graphics/blankDot.cur'), pointer");
```

`html` is already covered by `*`, so you should drop the `html` rule from your CSS.

Comment: @meo Thanks this works but you need to drop the colon `$("*").css("cursor", "url('/web/resources/graphics/blankdot.cur'), pointer")`